# is it safe to add UIView to another so that child view's frame is much larger than parent's frame

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I want to add a UIView to another UIView so that child view covers all of its parent.

Initially I did:

```
UIView * childVU;
childVU = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:parentVU.frame];
```

When I added childVU to parentVU, childVU's top was lower than that of parentVU.

so I did:

```
childVU = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 10000.0, 10000.0)];
```

It is running correctly on simulators, but is it really safe to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where on the right track with your first code.
Except you should have used `bounds` and not `frame`, since the frame is relative to the parent.

```
UIView * childVU;
childVU = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:parentVU.bounds];
```

Although making a child view large will work, it not the correct way to do it, but if `clipsToBounds` set to `YES` on the view or `masksToBounds` is set to `YES` it will nog draw child views larger then it own size.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's fine. Ensure your parent view has `clipToBounds` disabled prior to displaying the content. Also that is a massive view size and it will be unsupported on older devices. If you are actually using content this size you should place it in a `UIScrollView` or a `CATiledLayer`.